# Windows 10 bash(ubuntu sub system)

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

Windows 10 bash (ubuntu sub system ) I have installed feature after anniversary update My question is what is bash as sub system ,how it works and apps like gcc ,g++ installed in bash(ubuntu sub) can be used by program in windows e.g can code blocks ide installed in windows detect these apps (gcc,g++) i.e can i use any library or app installed in ubuntu from windows like gcc compiler for code blocks installed in windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Can I use any library or app installed in Ubuntu from Windows?

No.

> Software you install in the Bash shell is restricted to the Bash shell. You can’t access it from the Command Prompt, PowerShell, or elsewhere in Windows.
>
> Software in the Bash shell also can’t interact directly with or launch Windows programs, although the Bash environment and Windows have access to the same files on your computer.

Source [How to Install and Use the Linux Bash Shell on Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)